# Infinite loop in useEffect with empty dependency array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, redux-toolkit

While debugging, I found that the infinite loop occurs when trying to change the state of `isLoading` in the `fulfilled` case

```
./slice.js

const fetchMovies = createAsyncThunk(...)

extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(fetchMovies.pending, (state) => {
        state.isLoading = true
      })
      .addCase(fetchMovies.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false // this line triggers the loop
        }
      })


./Component.jsx

export function SearchForm() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  // fetching to update the default state of movies
  useEffect( () => {
    dispatch(fetchMovies('Titanic'))
  }, [])
  

  return (...)
}
```

Comment: How are you even using `useEffect` in a `slice`? I'm guessing you haven't formatted the question properly. Please separate different parts and provide the correct code.

Comment: it is written here for short, I'm of course using it in a component

Comment: Please edit the question and provide the correct format.

Comment: I did. can check it out

Answer (score 0):

Your code is still very incomplete. I have no idea why you're using `useEffect` to fetch the movies. Because of the way your `SearchForm` component is laid out, I guess that the user searches for a movie title, submits and then the action of fetching the movies based on the title gets dispatched.

So in that scenario, using `useEffect` is not appropriate and you have to use a function to handle the submit.

```
import { useState } from "React"

const SearchForm = () => {

const [input, setInput] = useState("");

const handleSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (!input) return;

  dispatch(fetchMovies(input));
}

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input value={input} onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}></input>
      <button type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  )
}
```

Comment: I have to show something to users when the page is opened for the first time. it didn't work - that was the problem